# General question about university modules

Tags: general-topology

I am an undergraduate student about to pick options for my 2nd year at uni. Topology is one of the optional courses and I just want to know a bit about the content because it’s new.

I enjoy doing the algebra content, things like linear algebra and group theory have been strong points. On the other hand, I’ve found real analysis hard and struggled getting to grips with it.

What is topology comparable to? Is it more related to analysis or algebra or is it an entirely new skill?

Comment: I suggest getting ahold of the text used by your school for that course.  Looking over that will give you a much better idea of the material than anyone could give you in a few sentences here.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a typical first semester topology course is more analysis than algebra (point-set topology), but a typical second semester course flips that script, being more algebra than analysis (algebraic topology).

Both analysis and algebra use methods from topology in more advanced classes, so you should have some exposure to topology if you want to continue into research in either of those fields, but topology is a fairly broad field in its own right, and in many ways can be considered independently from either analysis or algebra.

Comment: Ok thank you! Definitely sounds worth doing maybe just need to take it and find out whether I like it, can always drop it!